# multi switch configuration using cisco packet tracer

Tags: networking, cisco, vlan

I have the  network configuration as follows [image: NetworkConfigurationWithLinks]

I have tried to ping 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.101 and it succeeds.

I have tried to ping 192.168.50.100 to 192.168.50.101 which is on vlan 50 and it fails.

The simulation diagram showed arp is not being forwarded from switch1 to switch2.

[image: Simulation diagram]

I have configured both the sides of switch to trunk.

[image: Trunk configuration on switch]

I am just learning on vlans and trunking.

Can anybody please explains what is the configuration I am missing?

If i remove switch1 and connect switch0 to switch2 everything works fine.

EDIT

Switch0 vlan configuration.

[image: switch0 vlan configuration]

Switch1 vlan configuration. [image: switch1 vlan configuration]

Switch2 vlan configuration

[image: switch2 vlan configuration]

Comment: put "do show vlan brief" in your console switch 0, 1 and 2 please and paste it here

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to add at switch0 and switch2 in the assigned ports, in my case:

```
Switch0(config-if)#int fastEthernet0/2
Switch0(config-if)#switchport access vlan 50
Switch0(config-if)#switchport mode access

Switch2(config-if)#int fastEthernet0/3
Switch2(config-if)#switchport access vlan 50
Switch2(config-if)#switchport mode access
```

You can also add vlan 50 to switch1 (I don't know how you have it).

```
Switch1(config)#vlan 50
Switch1(config-vlan)#name VLAN0050
Switch1(config-vlan)#exit
Switch1(config)#
```

where the Ethernet cable connects from the PC to the switch.

[image: pkt]

As you can see PC0 goes to PC2 successfully and PC1 goes to PC3 successfully.

Comment: It is working now. I have missed the configuration of vlan at switch2. Thanks for update

Answer (score 0):

**Write This Command on Switch 0 & 2 :**

```
Switch#configure terminal 
Switch(config)#vlan 50
Switch(config-vlan)#name test
Switch(config-vlan)#exit 
Switch(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/2
Switch(config-if)#switchport mode access 
Switch(config-if)#switchport access vlan 50
Switch(config-if)#exit
Switch(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/3
Switch(config-if)#switchport mode trunk
Switch(config-if)#exit
Switch(config)#exit 
Switch#write memory
```

**Switch 1 :**
*in Switch 1 You Must Define Vlan's or You Can Delete This Switch and Connect Switch 0 & 2 Direct With Trunk or You Have Anoter Option Like VTP mode .*

**Whatever This Command Write On Switch 1 :**

```
Switch(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/1
Switch(config-if)#switchport mode trunk 
Switch(config-if)#exit 
Switch(config)#interface fastEthernet 0/2
Switch(config-if)#switchport mode trunk 
Switch(config-if)#exit
Switch(config)#vlan 50
Switch(config-vlan)#name test
Switch(config-vlan)#exit 
Switch(config)#exit 
Switch#write memory
```

[image]